# Cannot access my list from OnGet() in OnPost()

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am making a page where the unapproved users are getting approved so they can login to the site.
That is how the page looks

[The Approve Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8c72.png)

This my PageModel

```
 public class ApproveModel : PageModel
{
   
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public List<ApproveUsers> Users { get; set; } = new List<ApproveUsers>();
    public ApproveModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public class ApproveUsers
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        foreach (var user in _userManager.Users)
        {
            var approveUsers = new ApproveUsers
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
            };

            if(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user,"Approved"))
            {
                approveUsers.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                approveUsers.IsSelected = false;
            }
            Users.Add(approveUsers);
        }

        return Page();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Users.Count(); i++)
        {
         var user =  await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Users[i].UserId);
            IdentityResult result = null;
            if (Users[i].IsSelected && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Approved")))
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Approved");
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }     
        }
        return Page();
    }

}
```

And this is my html for the page take ApproveModel as MODEL

```
<form method="post">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Approve users</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @for(int i =0; i < Model.Users.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-check m-1">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].UserId" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.Users[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].IsSelected" >
                    @Model.Users[i].UserId
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is in the ApproveModel OnPostt method when i try to go through the list its Count is zero which means it is empty. I do not know how to access the Users Value from the OnGet method in the OnPost Method

Thankk you in advanceeee <333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[BindProperty]`,so that you can bind data to `public List<ApproveUsers> Users { get; set; }` when form posts.Here is [an official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#targets).

```
[BindProperty]
public List<ApproveUsers> Users { get; set; } = new List<ApproveUsers>();
```